# Visualfoce: Date format is shown as 217 July 2020

Tags: html, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have a problem with the date function in visualforce.

My code looks as following:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, DD MMMM YYYY}">
                    <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Invoice_Due_Date__c}" /> </apex:outputText>
```

Invoice_Due_Date__c is a simple datepicker with no specific rules.

Everytime a date is selected month and year are shown correctly, but day always has numbers higher than 150, which makes absolutly no sense.

Do I have to change the code or the settings of the custom field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualforce follows Java's "[simple date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)" rules. [`<apex:outputText>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) documentation has example of `yyyy.MM.dd` rendering to `2004.11.20`.

Capital `D` means day-in-year, 1 to 366 range :)

Pay attention to capital `Y` too, you want it lowercase. Uppercase one is used in some tricky reporting like if you have [factory/warehouse/accounting team insisting new year doesn't always start on January 1st.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%934%E2%80%935_calendar) Sometimes they'll swear to you July started on June 29th ;) Crazy people